# If I use my school's access key to activate Windows 10 Education on my personal computer (at home) will the school be able to monitor my activity?

Tags: privacy, windows-10

I downloaded Windows 10 Pro (unactivated) when I first built my PC, but was given an activation key from my school's IT website after logging in. I entered the key which activated windows and now I am using Windows Education. How much (if at all) can they monitor my activity (what applications I have open, what files I have on my PC, what websites I visit, etc)

Answer (score 1):

An activation code does only that: it activates the Windows license. It doesn't add the installation under the control of your school, like logging in to the computer with an organizational account would do (Intune, Autopilot etc.).

However, using such licenses on personal devices might be a violation of the license terms. But that's a bit out of scope for this question and more of their problem than yours.